# Translating UI resources for Windows store apps

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

In XAML for strings that are to be displayed in localized language we need to identify its Width property and access it using **x:Uid** attribute. [image]

If particular string width falls short of space how we can attain flexible layout and also we know German and Finnish require more space than English for text.
Is there any alternate way to get localized strings in XAML.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the strings in code via a [`ResourceLoader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206021.aspx) object.